# Magento 2: How to increase customer login session?

Tags: magento2, customer-session

I want to increase customer login session.

Please tell me how can i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it here:

> Stores --> Configuration --> Web --> Default Cookie Sessions

[image]

I hope this will helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

Session lifetime could be handled through admin:

1. On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Configuration.
2. If you have multiple stores, set the Store View chooser in the upper-right corner to the store where the configuration applies.
3. In the panel on the left under General, choose Web.
4. Expand the Default Cookie Settings section.
5. To change the default, clear the Use system value checkbox. Then, enter the new value in seconds.
6. Tap Save Config.

Reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/customer-online-options.html